# Prove the matrix satisfies the equation $A^2 -4A-5I=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-functions

How to prove that
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 2 \\
  2 & 1 & 2 \\
  2 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

satisfies the equation $A^2 -4A-5I=0$?

Comment: If nothing else, just compute the expression..

Comment: In such easy example I would simple calculate that out.

Comment: I know that but i wonder how ease as is.Thnx very much

Comment: @Amzoti yes written correctly.

Comment: What's $5I$?${}$

Comment: @Shahar I is the identity matrix

Comment: In a more general case you could diagonalize the matrix and get something of the form $A = Q^TDQ$. You then get $A^2- 4A -5I = Q^TD^2Q-4Q^TDQ - 5Q^TIQ = Q^T(D^2-4D-5I)Q$, for which the equality is much easier to check.

Comment: Compute the eigenvalues, that will probably work. Then use Cayley-Hamilton Theorem or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$A^2 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 9 & 8 & 8 \\
 8 & 9 & 8 \\
 8 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$-4A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -4 & -8 & -8 \\
 -8 & -4 & -8 \\
 -8 & -8 & -4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$A^2  - 4A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This is just as easy as any other way for this problem.

Comment: Thnx i got what you are talking about .

Comment: Nice explication!

Answer (score 3):

$A=2J-I$, where $J$ is the all-one matrix with $J^2=3J$. Therefoer
$$
A^2-4A-5I=(2J-I)^2-4(2J-I)-5I=4J^2-12J=0.
$$

Comment: Excellent idea thnx.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to sped up the calculation (supposing you are doing it on your own) you can use this approach.

Let's take the equation
$$ A^2 - 4A - 5I = 0.$$
And now forget about the matrices. What we have is simple quadratic equation in $x$ written as
$$ x^2 - 4x - 5 = 0,$$
now just find the roots
$$ (x-5)(x+1) = 0.$$
Let's get back to that matrix
$$(A-5I)(A+I) = 0.$$
Simple calculations give
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 2  &2\\
2  & -4 &2\\
2  & 2  &-4
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2  &2\\
2  & 2 &2\\
2  & 2  &2
\end{pmatrix} = 0.
$$

And now it is very simple since you divide by 2
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 2  &2\\
2  & -4 &2\\
2  & 2  &-4
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &1\\
1 & 1 &1\\
1 & 1 &1
\end{pmatrix} = 0.
$$
Multiplying those matrices is just adding all the elements in each row of the first matrix. So it is $0$ everywhere. Such tricks might come in handy in more complicated examples.

Comment: Excellent idea thnx.

Comment: I am glad I could be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to note that $x^2 - 4x - 5 = (x-5)(x+1)$ so if we wanted to calculate this matrix $A^2 - 4A + 5I$ we can just calculate $(A-5I)(A+I)$.

This might not be much easier, especially just for a quadratic, but it does reduce the number of times you have to calculate a product of matrices, and the number of times you have to add them up.

The other ways given are perfectly good too, I just happen to prefer solving this sort of problem this way.